# URL data passing and JQuery Effect

Tags: php, html, url, get, jquery-mobile

I have the following code in my web app

```
<li><a href="javascript:this.next('A')">A</a></li>
```

And the javascript function 'next' creates and loads the following link when the above item is clicked:

```
.../testing.php?first=A#result
```

It works fine, It calls the 'result' anchor, and I extract the value of 'first' via:

```
$first=$_GET['first'];
```

but the problem is, I am using JQuery Mobile and the sliding effect that usually happens between anchor switches doesnt work. It simply loads another page.

I tested out a bunch of different ways of passing the data through the URL, and it seems the slidin g effect only happens when the anchor tag immediately follows the 'testing.php' portion of the url like this:

```
.../testing.php#result
```

Is there a way to pass the data in a URL after the anchor tag and extract it with php?
OR
Is there a way to force the sliding effect?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the new page into the dom via jQM's ajax-handling of links then you can omit the hash portion of the url. When jQM loads the new page into the dom it only load the portion of the page within the `data-role="page"` element. So if you use a url like:

```
/testing.php?first=A
```

and `testing.php` outputs a page like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="testing_<?php echo $_GET['first']; ?>">
    ...
</div>
```

then the rest of the website can use the id (`testing_A`) output by `testing.php` to reference the newly added page.